# Which one is a better interface to save a raw pointer(provided by the user) to shared_ptr

Tags: c++, design-patterns, boost

In the strategy design pattern, I need to store a reference to the Compositor in the Composition(pp315 [GOF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)). For one of the implementation method, the client will pass a reference of the Compositor to the constructor of Composition, I would like to know which API interface is better from design point of view.

For example:

1> `A(boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr)` // assume that ptr referring to the Compositor

2> `B(int* ptr)`                   // assume that ptr referring to the Compositor

I have given the following example to illustrate the usage of two different interfaces. They are NOT the implementation of strategy design pattern! The code is provided to help me demonstrate the different ways that the client can call the Composition with the pass-in parameter of a reference to Compositor.

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
using namespace std; // for convenience
class A {
private:    
    boost::shared_ptr<int> m_sPtr;
public:
    A(boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr) : m_sPtr(ptr) {}
    //...
};

class B {
private:    
    boost::shared_ptr<int> m_sPtr;
public:
    B(int* ptr) : m_sPtr(ptr) {}
    //...
};

int _tmain(int /*argc*/, _TCHAR* /*argv*/[])
{
    boost::shared_ptr<int> temPtr(new int(100));
    A a(temPtr);

    B b(new int(200));

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: The best solution in this case is not to use a pointer at all.  And I don't think I've ever seen a case where it was appropriate to dynamically allocate a single `int`.

Comment: @JamesKanze, please read my comment that has indicated the code is provided as an example and `ptr` is assumed to point to a reference to Compositor.

Comment: You might want a shared int, if for example, it is going to be a reference-count.

Comment: @q0987 I don't have my copy of the GoF here, and I'm not that familiar with the Compositor pattern, but most of the GoF patterns suppose raw pointers, and a lot of them will not work with `shared_ptr` (they contain cycles).  So you really have to analyse the pattern.

Comment: @q0987 I've just looked up the Compositor pattern.  The descriptions were a bit vague, but from what little I gathered, there's really no place in it that you'd want to use a `shared_ptr`; just using raw pointers through out seems reasonable, or a `scoped_ptr` in the containing class.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, the place where the resource is created is responsible for where it gets released, therefore you should not, on the whole, take a raw pointer unless your class is the smart pointer.

And soon, with variadic templates in C++11 you will be able to use make_shared() which means you don't call new at all either.

If you want the object to keep a shared copy, pass it a `shared_ptr`. Incidentally, the one who created it knows how it needs to be destroyed too, so may put in a custom deleter.

Comment: Your first sentence sounds like a contradiction.  If you use `shared_ptr`, you are explicitly decoupling release from where the resource was created.

Comment: No, the release is in the deleter that is in the shared_ptr. Yes, shared_ptr gives you a "default" one, but really it is the place where you create the shared_ptr where the deleter is being defined.

Comment: But that's not when it's being called.  It's being called at some more or less random point in the future, independently of what the creator might have planned.

Comment: Why argue about the meaning of "responsible" in CashCow's remark? The purpose of `shared_ptr` is to enable the person who creates the resource to control *how* it is destroyed, and the various users of the resource to collectively determine *when* it is destroyed.

Comment: the creator is taking care of its eventual disposition. It doesn't know when this will take place, but it is being already prepared for.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to store the the pointer in a `shared_ptr`, then you *have* to accept it as a `shared_ptr`, not a raw pointer (unless you're writing a smart pointer class of your own, that uses `shared_ptr` underneath. But you aren't).

The reason is just that the user might already have their resource in a `shared_ptr`, for example if they've cleverly put it there as soon as it was created. If you create another `shared_ptr` for the same resource then there are two things that will eventually delete it, and that's a bug.

Potentially you could work around that by using `enable_shared_from_this` with your Compositor class, but unless there's some good reason you can't take a `shared_ptr` in the first place, there's no point.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to always (with very few exceptions in special cases) store a pointer allocated with `new` immediately in some kind of smart pointer.  Therefore the procedure used in `A` is best.  That interface explicitly enforces that the pointer passed as the argument *will be* stored in a smart pointer.  Your class `B` does not guarantee that at all.  In fact, even if you are not careful in your calling code and call write `A(new int(100));`, you can be sure that pointer will not accidentally be leaked because a (temporary) shared_ptr will be constructed from your raw pointer and then passed to A's constructor.  The interface used in `A` announces, "Your pointer will be taken care of!" while the interface in `B` says, "Hmm... I don't know what will happen to it!"